# Browser URL not changing when redirect to default controller , Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

Hi  i am using codeigniter , When i type my base URL in browser , i want to redirect to a default controller .

My Base URL

```
http://localhost/itams/index.php
```

My Default route

```
$route['default_controller'] = "new_starter/listing";
```

My Problem is when i type `http://localhost/itams/index.php` in Browser , it correctly redirect to the `new_starter/listing` page , but the Browser URL is not changing . it shows as  `http://localhost/itams/index.php`.

> Is that the default behavior ?
>
> How can i change the Browser URL ?
>
> Do i have to do a manual redirect using `header()`  ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: change also base url?

Comment: @RakeshSharma Sorry i did not get your point , can you please explain :)

Comment: it should be redirect on default controller. have you any routing? also remove index.php from url

Comment: @RakeshSharma defalut controller is 'new_starter/listing' , it is redirecting to default controller , but the browser URL stays at 'http://localhost/itams/index.php' , i thought i is bit misleading .

Comment: no i haven't . is there any connection with URL redirection and 'index.php' ?

Comment: after removing index.php keep your base url = http://localhost/itams/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69106/discussion-between-rakesh-sharma-and-kanishka-panamaldeniya).

Comment: Do you want "localhost/new_starter/listing" on the url ?

Comment: I have removed index.php . but still the same

Comment: okey you can get this but these steps 
Step 1 : Go to confing.php write base_url ="http://localhost/itams" and  remove "index.php" in $config['index_page'] 
Step 2 : go to route.php and write $route['default_controller'] = "new_starter/listing"; (Make Sure here your controller is "new_starter" and function in that controller is "listing" )
step 3 : Then just simple hit url "http://localhost/itams" in your browser.

Comment: @Rishi , I have already done this , "new_starter/listing" page correctly loading but the URL stays in "localhost/itams" , seems that it is the default behavior of Codeigniter ,also Rakesh Sharma has confirmed that it is the default behavior .

Comment: Then one is the simplest way is that create an default controller with index function and the code of index function is 
public function index(){
redirect("new_starter/listing");
}  and  $route['default_controller'] = "Your_controller_with_function"; 
it's automatically redirect you site with "http://localhost/itams/new_starter/listing"

Comment: @Rishi , Hmm , I also Thought that way , but i am not sure that is the best Way , do you think it is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69110/discussion-between-rishi-and-kanishka-panamaldeniya).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that the default behavior ?

Ans. - **YES**

> How can i change the Browser URL ?

you need to put this code at start of your **default controller method**

```
    if($this->uri->total_segments() === 0){
        redirect('controller/method','refresh');
    }
```

**i.e.** in your case `listing` method of `new_starter` controller.

finally it should look something like this

```
Class New_starter extends APP_Controller {
  ...
    public function listing(){
            if($this->uri->total_segments() === 0){
                redirect('new_starter/listing','refresh');
            }
           // rest of your method code.
    }
  ...
}
```